# Adding Music To Java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I'm making connect four for my high school cpt and I'm trying to add music to the background and for sound effects. My teacher gave me some code to work with, but since I have never worked with sound I don't understand how to use it. Can someone please explain the code that I was given? Thanks for your help!

```
try {
  AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("SoundFile.wav"));//use wav. mp3 doesn't work
  Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
  clip.open(audio);
  clip.start();
} 
catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uae) {
  System.out.println(uae);
} 
catch(IOException ioe) { 
  System.out.println(ioe);
} 
catch(LineUnavailableException lua) { 
  System.out.println(lua);
}
```

Comment: i guess that code is inside a method? call the method and the "clip" will start no?

Comment: Take a look at [Java Sound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html)

Comment: @Rich I tried doing this but I'm getting an error saying it cannot find symbol in the first two lines within the try and also in the catch.

Comment: You need to import those classes. There should be a way of doing this in your IDE (e.g. in Eclipse the default is Ctrl+Shift+o)

Comment: @M21B8 Yeah you were right, I had to import some classes. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: I'll add it as answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the following classes from the relevant packages:

```
AudioInputStream 
UnsupportedAudioFileException
IOException 
LineUnavailableException
File
```